# Android: application crashing because of firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Today I tested my app on a new device (see below) and I'm getting an exception right at launch. I can't event start the main activity.

**Device**: Genymotion Samsung Galaxy S2 - Android 4.1.1 - API 16

No google play services installed.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.g
     at com.google.firebase.b.a(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4560)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

gradle build:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

   defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.app"
     minSdkVersion 10
     targetSdkVersion 21
     multiDexEnabled true
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
}
```

Is it crashing because of missing Play Services?

Note: I have implemented `firebase` about a month ago, and It's working on other devices.

Comment: please update play services in your  Genymotion Samsung  !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have `multiDexEnabled true` in your build.gradle file, you are missing `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` in your dependencies.  I doubt that Mulidex is working.  Review the [Multidex configuration instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) and make sure you have done everything correctly.

Also, it is not good practice to include `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'`.  That adds *all* the Google Play and Firebase libraries to you app, increasing build time and the size of the APK file. Replace the dependency on `play-services:9.4.0` with only the libraries you need.   A list of the Google Play libraries is [provided here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), the Firebase libraries are [listed here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this *apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'* to the end of your gradle build file

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, Firebase requires Google play services. As mentioned here in the release announcement for Google Play Services 9.0:
[Google Play Services 9.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2016/05/google-play-services-90-updates.html?m=1)

> Firebase was built using Google Play services 9.0

Comment: I have tested on a Samung Galaxy S5 device (4.4.2) with Google Play Services installed, and it's keep crashing.

Comment: Also, the google play service installed on S5 is 9.4.52

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the Application Tag on manifest file:

android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"